# How to group difference of date values by range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have strung together a series of queries that I have had working as individual queries or as a query with one subquery.
I need to show the total number of jobs that have a particular status grouped by range of the number of days a job has been in that status.

E.g. (random data for concept purpose)

```
fldFranchiseCode Status  0-9 10-19 20-29 etc
Franchise A      Status1  1    0     3
Franchise A      Status2  2    1     4
Franchise A      Status4  3    2     1
Franchise B      Status2  1    6     4
```

This is what I have so far, but I'm getting a SQL error - 'Incorrect syntax near 'pvt'.'

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT  fldFranchiseCode, Range AS [Day Range], COUNT(*) AS Jobs
FROM    (SELECT fldFranchiseCode, CASE WHEN Days BETWEEN 0 AND 9 THEN '0- 9'
             WHEN Days BETWEEN 10 AND 19 THEN '10-19'
             WHEN Days BETWEEN 20 AND 29 THEN '20-29'
             WHEN Days BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN '30-39'
             WHEN Days BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN '40-49'
             WHEN Days BETWEEN 50 AND 59 THEN '50-59'
             WHEN Days BETWEEN 60 AND 69 THEN '60-69'
             WHEN Days BETWEEN 70 AND 79 THEN '70-79'
             WHEN Days BETWEEN 80 AND 89 THEN '80-89'
             WHEN Days BETWEEN 90 AND 99 THEN '90-99' 
             ELSE 'Over 100' END AS Range
        FROM    (SELECT  fldRecordID,
        T.fldInquiryRecordID,
        fldDate,
        NextDate,
        DATEDIFF("D", fldDate, NextDate) AS Days,
        fldStatus,
        fldFranchiseCode
FROM    (   SELECT  fldRecordID, 
                    T1.fldInquiryRecordID,
                    fldDate,
                    (   SELECT  MIN([fldDate]) 
                        FROM    tblStatusLog T2
                        WHERE   T2.[fldInquiryRecordID] = T1.[fldInquiryRecordID]
                        AND     T2.[fldDate] > T1.[fldDate]
                    ) AS NextDate,
                    fldStatus,
                    fldFranchiseCode
            FROM    tblStatusLog T1
            JOIN tblInquiry ON T1.fldInquiryRecordID = tblInquiry.fldInquiryRecordID
        ) AS T
GROUP BY [Day Range],fldFranchiseCode) q1
pivot
(max(jobs)
 FOR [Day Range] IN ([0- 9],[10-19],[20-29],[30-39],[40-49],[50-59],
                     [60-69],[70-79],[80-89],[90-99],[Over 100])
)as pvt
```

Any help much appreciated

Comment: just count the number of opening brackets and the closing brackets. You will see the discrepancy. Fix it

Comment: I've tried that and come up with 6 opening brackets and four closing so obviously that's a problem.  The question is where do I place the extra two closing brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper indenting will help identify the syntax error. (Well, or avoiding nesting queries four levels deep in the first place.)

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT fldFranchiseCode, ...
  FROM
  ( 
    SELECT fldFranchiseCode, CASE ...
    FROM
    (
      SELECT fldRecordID, ...
      FROM
      (
        SELECT fldRecordID, ...
        FROM    tblStatusLog T1
        JOIN tblInquiry ON T1.fldInquiryRecordID = tblInquiry.fldInquiryRecordID
      ) AS T
      GROUP BY Range, fldFranchiseCode
               ^^^^^ note, can't group by an alias here
    ) q1
  ) AS q2 -- you need this one
) AS q3   -- and this one too
pivot
(
  max(jobs)
  FOR [Day Range] IN ([0- 9],[10-19],[20-29],[30-39],[40-49],[50-59],
                     [60-69],[70-79],[80-89],[90-99],[Over 100])
) as pvt;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That got it sorted and allowed me to see where the rest of the components of this query should go.